# Django: Create JSON object from model to return to template

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am working on a Django-based Quiz that will be rendered with the help of Javascript. Each Quiz consists of a number of Questions, which basically have a question text and a number of Choices (which in turn can be correct or incorrect - multiple correct answers are theoretically possible).

I want to call get_all_questions_json from the template to then receive something like this:

```
{
    {
        "Question 1":
        [
            ["Answer 1-1", true],
            ["Answer 1-2", false],
            ["Answer 1-3", false]
        ]
    },

    {
        "Question 2":
        [
            ["Answer 1-1", false],
            ["Answer 1-2", true],
            ["Answer 1-3", false]
        ]
    },  

    {
        "Question 3":
        [
            ["Answer 1-1", false],
            ["Answer 1-2", false],
            ["Answer 1-3", true]
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

**models.py:**

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    # to do feedback texts

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Quizzes"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # Newly created object, set slug
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Quiz, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_all_questions(self):
        return self.question_set.all()

    def get_all_questions_json(self):
        #

class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    iscorrect = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: Please check your models, how can Quiz have self.question_set while Question has no foreign key as Quiz.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the questions in your target quiz and create a list that you could later pass to `json.dumps`.

```
def get_all_questions_json(self):
    import json
    quiz_data = []
    for question in self.question_set.all():
        answers = []
        quiz_data.append({
            'text': question.text,
            'answers': [
                [answer.text, answer.is_correct]
                for answer in question.answer_set.all()
            ],
        })
    return json.dumps(quiz_data)
```

The output will be a little different to what you stated, something like:

```
[
    {
        text: "Question 1",
        answers: [
            ["Answer 1-1", true],
            ["Answer 1-2", false],
            ["Answer 1-3", false]
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "Question 2",
        answers: [
            ["Answer 1-1", false],
            ["Answer 1-2", true],
            ["Answer 1-3", false]
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "Question 3",
        answers: [
            ["Answer 1-1", false],
            ["Answer 1-2", false],
            ["Answer 1-3", true]
        ]
    }
]
```